# Playing a choice of 3 sound files

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple function that plays a specific sound file based on the argument you pass to it. I understand that I need to use something like this:

```
const audio = new Audio("freejazz.wav");
audio.play()
```

But what would you do if you had 3 different sound files? A, I supposed to have `const audio1 = new Audio("paidjazz.wave");` etc?

I will be calling these files regularly, so will the 'new' keyword keep calling fresh instances, leading to a memory leak?

How can I create a function that plays the sound if I use something like `play("MySoundName")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) the documentation seems to suggest that the construction of a new `Audio` object sets up a "wrapper" (not sure if that's quite the term I'm after here, but I'll stick with it for now) around an audio file with methods you can call etc.

The `new` keyword will create fresh instances, yes. So you should probably do outside of wherever the audio is being played from so that it only happens once.

i.e:
The following will play pop 100 times, but unless you put `new Audio()` inside the loop I would not expect it to keep creating new instances

```
const pop =new Audio('pop.mp3');
for(let i=0; i<=100; i++) {
    // play pop
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. All working now.